# Application not working as expected

Tags: java, math

I have a standalone Java application below that is:

- Generating a random line
- Applied to a 2D grid where each cell value is the distance along the line perpindicular to the line
- Finds the rise/run and attempts to calculate the original linear equation from the grid
- Applies new line to another grid and prints out the greatest difference compared to the first grid

I expected the two grids to have identical values.  The gradient lines may be different since the lines can extend outside the area of the grid, but should be similar and in two cases identical.

So is the problem a poor understanding of math, a bug in my code or a misunderstanding of floating point values?

```
import java.awt.geom.Point2D;
import java.awt.geom.Line2D;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public final class TestGradientLine {
    private static int SIZE = 3;

    public TestGradientLine() {
        super();
    }

    //y = mx + b
    //b = y - mx
    //m is rise / run = gradient
    //width and height of bounding box
    //for a box 10x10 then width and height are 9,9
    public static Line2D getGradientLine(double run, double rise, double width, double height, double x, double y) {
        if (run == 0 && rise == 0) {
            return new Line2D.Double(x, y, x + width, y + height);
        }

        //calculate hypotenuse
        //check for a vertical line
        if (run == 0) {
            return new Line2D.Double(x, y, x, y + height);
        }
        //check for a horizontal line
        if (rise == 0) {
            return new Line2D.Double(x, y, x + width, y);
        }
        //calculate gradient
        double m = rise / run;
        Point2D start;
        Point2D opposite;
        if (m < 0) {
            //lower left
            start = new Point2D.Double(x, y + height); 
            opposite = new Point2D.Double(x + width, y); 

        } else {
            //upper left 
            start = new Point2D.Double(x, y);
            opposite = new Point2D.Double(x + width, y + height); 
        }
        double b = start.getY() - (m * start.getX());

        //now calculate another point along the slope
        Point2D next = null;
        if (m > 0) {
            next = new Point2D.Double(start.getX() + Math.abs(run), start.getY() + Math.abs(rise));
        } else {
            if (rise < 0) {
                next = new Point2D.Double(start.getX() + run, start.getY() + rise);
            } else {
                next = new Point2D.Double(start.getX() - run, start.getY() - rise);
            }
        }
        final double actualWidth = width;
        final double actualHeight = height;
        final double a = Math.sqrt((actualWidth * actualWidth) + (actualHeight * actualHeight));
        extendLine(start, next, a);
        Line2D gradientLine = new Line2D.Double(start, next);
        return gradientLine;

    }

    public static void extendLine(Point2D p0, Point2D p1, double toLength) {
        final double oldLength = p0.distance(p1);
        final double lengthFraction =
                oldLength != 0.0 ? toLength / oldLength : 0.0;
        p1.setLocation(p0.getX() + (p1.getX() - p0.getX()) * lengthFraction,
            p0.getY() + (p1.getY() - p0.getY()) * lengthFraction);
    }

    public static Line2D generateRandomGradientLine(int width, int height) {
        //so true means lower and false means upper
        final boolean isLower = Math.random() > .5;
        final Point2D start = new Point2D.Float(0, 0);
        if (isLower) {
            //change origin for lower left corner
            start.setLocation(start.getX(), height - 1);
        }
        //radius of our circle
        double radius = Math.sqrt(width * width + height * height);
        //now we want a random theta
        //x = r * cos(theta)
        //y = r * sin(theta)
        double theta = 0.0;
        if (isLower) {
            theta = Math.random() * (Math.PI / 2);
        } else {
            theta = Math.random() * (Math.PI / 2) + (Math.PI / 2);
        }

        int endX = (int)Math.round(radius * Math.sin(theta));
        int endY = (int)Math.round(radius * Math.cos(theta)) * -1;
        if (isLower) {
            endY = endY + (height - 1);
        }
        final Point2D end = new Point2D.Float(endX, endY);
        extendLine(start, end, radius);

        return new Line2D.Float(start, end);
    }

    public static Point2D getNearestPointOnLine(Point2D end, Line2D line) {
        final Point2D point = line.getP1();
        final Point2D start = line.getP2();
        double a = (end.getX() - point.getX()) * (start.getX() - point.getX()) + (end.getY() - point.getY()) * (start.getY() - point.getY());
        double b = (end.getX() - start.getX()) * (point.getX() - start.getX()) + (end.getY() - start.getY()) * (point.getY() - start.getY());
        final double x = point.getX() + ((start.getX() - point.getX()) * a)/(a + b);
        final double y = point.getY() + ((start.getY() - point.getY()) * a)/(a + b);
        final Point2D result = new Point2D.Double(x, y);
        return result;
    }

    public static double length(double x0, double y0, double x1, double y1) {
        final double dx = x1 - x0;
        final double dy = y1 - y0;

        return Math.sqrt(dx * dx + dy * dy);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        final Line2D line = generateRandomGradientLine(SIZE, SIZE);
        System.out.println("we're starting with line " + line.getP1() + " " + line.getP2());
        double[][] region = new double[SIZE][SIZE];
        //load up the region with data from our generated line
        for (int x = 0; x < SIZE; x++) {
            for (int y = 0; y < SIZE; y++) {
                final Point2D point = new Point2D.Double(x, y);
                final Point2D nearestPoint = getNearestPointOnLine(point, line);
                if (nearestPoint == null) {
                    System.err.println("uh -oh!");
                    return;
                }
                final double distance = length(line.getP1().getX(),
                        line.getP1().getY(), nearestPoint.getX() + 1,
                        nearestPoint.getY() + 1);

                region[x][y] = distance;    
            }
        }
        //now figure out what our line is from the region
        double runTotal = 0;
        double riseTotal = 0;
        double runCount = 0;
        double riseCount = 0;

        for (int x = 0; x < SIZE; x++) {
            for (int y = 0; y < SIZE; y++) {
                if (x < SIZE - 1) {
                    runTotal += region[x + 1][y] - region[x][y];
                    runCount++;
                }
                if (y < SIZE - 1) {
                    riseTotal += region[x][y + 1] - region[x][y];
                    riseCount++;
                }
            }
        }

        double run = 0;
        if (runCount > 0) {
            run = runTotal / runCount;
        }
        double rise = 0;
        if (riseCount > 0) {
            rise = riseTotal / riseCount;
        }

        System.out.println("rise is " + rise + " run is " + run);

        Line2D newLine = getGradientLine(run, rise, SIZE - 1, SIZE - 1, 0, 0);
        System.out.println("ending with line " + newLine.getP1() + " " + newLine.getP2());

        double worst = 0.0;
        int worstX = 0;
        int worstY = 0;
        for (int x = 0; x < SIZE; x++) {
            for (int y = 0; y < SIZE; y++) {
                final Point2D point = new Point2D.Double(x, y);
                final Point2D nearestPoint = getNearestPointOnLine(point, newLine);
                if (nearestPoint == null) {
                    System.err.println("uh -oh!");
                    return;
                }
                final double distance = length(line.getP1().getX(),
                        line.getP1().getY(), nearestPoint.getX() + 1,
                        nearestPoint.getY() + 1);
                final double diff = Math.abs(region[x][y] - distance);
                if (diff > worst) {
                    worst = diff;
                    worstX = x;
                    worstY = y;
                }
            }
        }
        System.out.println("worst is " + worst + " x: " + worstX + " y: " + worstY);
    }
}
```

Comment: Divide and conquer. Or better: Divide, unit-test and conquer.

Comment: Based on what you wrote above the code, I don't understand what you're trying to do.  Maybe try again?

Comment: Perhaps some clarification.  The code above does linear regression.  The rest of it is just testing for correctness.  Why is the linear regression returning seemingly incorrect values?

Comment: Should this be tagged homework? It feels like it should

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I have fixed your program.

a) I took out the integer cast.

b) I removed all the 'x + 1' and 'x - 1' fudges you had used.

I think when dealing with floats and doubles, subtracting '1' from the end of a line is a No-No! What is 1 anyway? - it's ok to do this just before you plot it on the screen once it's an integer. But not while calculating! line length is a 'zero-based' quantity.

This version returns approx 4E-16 always.

```
   import java.awt.geom.Point2D;
    import java.awt.geom.Line2D;
    import java.awt.geom.QuadCurve2D;
    import java.util.Iterator;
    import java.util.ArrayList;

    public final class TestGradientLine {

    private static int SIZE = 3;

    public TestGradientLine() {
        super();
    }

    //y = mx + b
    //b = y - mx
    //m is rise / run = gradient
    //width and height of bounding box
    //for a box 10x10 then width and height are 9,9
    public static Line2D getGradientLine(double run, double rise, double width, double height, double x, double y) {
        if (run == 0 && rise == 0) {
     return new Line2D.Double(x, y, x + width, y + height);
        }

        //calculate hypotenuse
        //check for a vertical line
        if (run == 0) {
     return new Line2D.Double(x, y, x, y + height);
        }
        //check for a horizontal line
        if (rise == 0) {
     return new Line2D.Double(x, y, x + width, y);
        }
        //calculate gradient
        double m = rise / run;
        Point2D start;
        Point2D opposite;
        if (m < 0) {
     //lower left
     start = new Point2D.Double(x, y + height); 
     opposite = new Point2D.Double(x + width, y); 

        } else {
     //upper left 
     start = new Point2D.Double(x, y);
     opposite = new Point2D.Double(x + width, y + height); 
        }
        double b = start.getY() - (m * start.getX());

        //now calculate another point along the slope
        Point2D next = null;
        if (m > 0) {
     next = new Point2D.Double(start.getX() + Math.abs(run), start.getY() + Math.abs(rise));
        } else {
     if (rise < 0) {
  next = new Point2D.Double(start.getX() + run, start.getY() + rise);
     } else {
  next = new Point2D.Double(start.getX() - run, start.getY() - rise);
     }
        }
        final double actualWidth = width;
        final double actualHeight = height;
        final double a = Math.sqrt((actualWidth * actualWidth) + (actualHeight * actualHeight));
        extendLine(start, next, a);
        Line2D gradientLine = new Line2D.Double(start, next);
        return gradientLine;

    }

    public static void extendLine(Point2D p0, Point2D p1, double toLength) {
        final double oldLength = p0.distance(p1);
        final double lengthFraction =
     oldLength != 0.0 ? toLength / oldLength : 0.0;
        p1.setLocation(p0.getX() + (p1.getX() - p0.getX()) * lengthFraction,
         p0.getY() + (p1.getY() - p0.getY()) * lengthFraction);
    }

    public static Line2D generateRandomGradientLine(int width, int height) {
        //so true means lower and false means upper
        final boolean isLower = Math.random() > .5;
        final Point2D start = new Point2D.Float(0, 0);
        if (isLower) {
     //change origin for lower left corner
     start.setLocation(start.getX(), height );
        }
        //radius of our circle
        double radius = Math.sqrt(width * width + height * height);
        //now we want a random theta
        //x = r * cos(theta)
        //y = r * sin(theta)
        double theta = 0.0;
        if (isLower) {
     theta = Math.random() * (Math.PI / 2);
        } else {
     theta = Math.random() * (Math.PI / 2) + (Math.PI / 2);
        }

        float endX = (float)(radius * Math.sin(theta));
        float endY = (float)(radius * Math.cos(theta)) * -1;
        if (isLower) {
     endY = endY + (height );
        }
        final Point2D end = new Point2D.Float(endX, endY);
        extendLine(start, end, radius);

        return new Line2D.Float(start, end);
    }

    public static Point2D getNearestPointOnLine(Point2D end, Line2D line) {
        final Point2D point = line.getP1();
        final Point2D start = line.getP2();
        double a = (end.getX() - point.getX()) * (start.getX() - point.getX()) + (end.getY() - point.getY()) * (start.getY() - point.getY());
        double b = (end.getX() - start.getX()) * (point.getX() - start.getX()) + (end.getY() - start.getY()) * (point.getY() - start.getY());
        final double x = point.getX() + ((start.getX() - point.getX()) * a)/(a+b);
        final double y = point.getY() + ((start.getY() - point.getY()) * a)/(a+b);
        final Point2D result = new Point2D.Double(x, y);
        return result;
    }

    public static double length(double x0, double y0, double x1, double y1) {
        final double dx = x1 - x0;
        final double dy = y1 - y0;

        return Math.sqrt(dx * dx + dy * dy);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        final Line2D line = generateRandomGradientLine(SIZE, SIZE);
        System.out.println("we're starting with line " + line.getP1() + " " + line.getP2());
        double[][] region = new double[SIZE][SIZE];
        //load up the region with data from our generated line
        for (int x = 0; x < SIZE; x++) {
     for (int y = 0; y < SIZE; y++) {
  final Point2D point = new Point2D.Double(x, y);
  final Point2D nearestPoint = getNearestPointOnLine(point, line);
  if (nearestPoint == null) {
      System.err.println("uh -oh!");
      return;
  }
  final double distance = length(line.getP1().getX(),
            line.getP1().getY(), nearestPoint.getX() ,
            nearestPoint.getY() );

  region[x][y] = distance;        
     }
        }
        //now figure out what our line is from the region
        double runTotal = 0;
        double riseTotal = 0;
        double runCount = 0;
        double riseCount = 0;

        for (int x = 0; x < SIZE; x++) {
     for (int y = 0; y < SIZE; y++) {
  if (x < SIZE - 1) {
      runTotal += region[x + 1][y] - region[x][y];
      runCount++;
  }
  if (y < SIZE - 1) {
      riseTotal += region[x][y + 1] - region[x][y];
      riseCount++;
  }
     }
        }

        double run = 0;
        if (runCount > 0) {
     run = runTotal / runCount;
        }
        double rise = 0;
        if (riseCount > 0) {
     rise = riseTotal / riseCount;
        }

        System.out.println("rise is " + rise + " run is " + run);

        Line2D newLine = getGradientLine(run, rise, SIZE, SIZE , 0, 0);
        System.out.println("ending with line " + newLine.getP1() + " " + newLine.getP2());

        double worst = 0.0;
        int worstX = 0;
        int worstY = 0;
        for (int x = 0; x < SIZE; x++) {
     for (int y = 0; y < SIZE; y++) {
  final Point2D point = new Point2D.Double(x, y);
  final Point2D nearestPoint = getNearestPointOnLine(point, newLine);
  if (nearestPoint == null) {
      System.err.println("uh -oh!");
      return;
  }
  final double distance = length(line.getP1().getX(),
            line.getP1().getY(), nearestPoint.getX() ,
            nearestPoint.getY() );
  final double diff = Math.abs(region[x][y] - distance);
  if (diff > worst) {
      worst = diff;
      worstX = x;
      worstY = y;
  }
     }
        }
        System.out.println("worst is " + worst + " x: " + worstX + " y: " + worstY);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

why do you multiply by -1 at the end of this line?

```
int endY = (int)Math.round(radius * Math.cos(theta)) * -1;
```

this means that endY is always negative except radius is below 0. (cosinus always returns positive value)

is this intended or am i getting something wrong?

regards

Comment: In the generateRandomGradientLine method, the end point to the line will often fall outside the bounds of the square (grid).  So if the upper left corner of the square is at 0,0, then a line originating at the lower left, heading upward but not quite vertical, will end outside the square above it.  Since y values are positive going down, then a negative Y value will result.  The randomly generated line is not trimmed to fit the square.

Answer (score 0):

You probably misunderstand float and/or double.  This is a common problem with any language that implements the ieee spec for floats and doubles, which Java, C, C++ and just about every other language does.
Essentially

```
double val = 0;  
for(int i=0;i<10;i++) {  
  val+=0.1;  
 System.out.println(val);
```

}

results in

```
0.1  
0.2  
0.30000000000000004  
0.4  
0.5  
0.6  
0.7  
0.7999999999999999  
0.8999999999999999  
0.9999999999999999
```

And sometimes even worse.  Either use BigDecimal, which alleviates a lot of the problem, or use integers.